# Breaking object into parts

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I have a model of piano that I would like to 3D print. 
The model comes as one part like in a picture below:[image]

I would like to print it in different parts like this:
[image]

Is there a way in Blender (plugin maybe) to create sort of joints (in a parts marked as red) so I can easily attach them after printing or this is something that needs to be done manually?

Comment: I don't think there are plugins... there are way too many joins that it would have to cover. You'll probably have to do it yourself. I can write an answer showing how if you would like.

Comment: Thanks, I know how. Just wondered if it can be done automatically

Answer (score 0):

What format is the model in? What about quads or mesh?
Quick answer is you could boolean a big box to cut the pieces off.